# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' ---for col in X_train.columns:

Tags: python, pandas, training-data, pearson-correlation

I keep running into this issue in my code, the error lies in the bolded lines. I cannot figure out resolution. Script is about 250 lines of code, so obviously i could not post all code here which may hinder anyone trying to help...thanks in advance - I am still beginner coder btw

---

```py
loans = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\train\Downloads\accepted-200000-new.csv',low_memory=True)

.....(more preprocessing code)


loans_train = loans.loc[loans['issue_d'] <  loans['issue_d'].quantile(0.9)]
loans_test =  loans.loc[loans['issue_d'] >= loans['issue_d'].quantile(0.9)]

loans_test.shape[0] / loans.shape[0]

loans_train.drop('issue_d', axis=1, inplace=True)
loans_test.drop('issue_d', axis=1, inplace=True)

y_train = loans_train['charged_off']
y_test = loans_test['charged_off']

X_train = loans_train.drop('charged_off', axis=1)
X_test = loans_test.drop('charged_off', axis=1)

del loans_train, loans_test

linear_dep = pd.DataFrame()

**for col in X_train.columns:
    linear_dep.loc[col, 'pearson_corr'] = X_train[col].corr(y_train)
linear_dep['abs_pearson_corr'] = abs(linear_dep['pearson_corr'])**

from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif
for col in X_train.columns:
    mask = X_train[col].notnull()
    (linear_dep.loc[col, 'F'], linear_dep.loc[col, 'p_value']) = f_classif(pd.DataFrame(X_train.loc[mask, col]), y_train.loc[mask])

linear_dep.sort_values('abs_pearson_corr', ascending=False, inplace=True)
linear_dep.drop('abs_pearson_corr', axis=1, inplace=True)

linear_dep.reset_index(inplace=True)
linear_dep.rename(columns={'index':'variable'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Some of  your data is strings.
Have you tried casting your data as int, by going int(data) within the code? or tried feeding in data that is integer based?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot locate where exactly the string of data is. It is all chopped up, currently guessing and checking with int(data)

Answer (score 0):

Why not check with `X_train.dtypes` - it would show you exactly what the data types are for your columns.

And to be safe, you can just do : `X_train[col].astype(int).corr(y_train)` - but, since you are running it over all columns, be sure to use a `try` because you may have columns that are purely strings, and should be omitted anyway!

Comment: ok I ran "print(X_train.dtypes)" and did not see any strings listed, only objects int64, float64s, and uint8s.

Comment: I used " X_train[col].astype(int).corr(y_train)"  and was returned with "ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Comment: Oh! can you do a `try` and `except` block? So, `try` and then your `corr` line - and if `except` print the `col` - would atleast show you the offending column!

Comment: btw, I guess you reassigned the values in X_train? So, `X_train = X_train.fillna(0)`?

Comment: Did so with dataframe, but just did "X_train = X_train.fillna(0)"  actually might have helped - unfortunately new error was raised.

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jan-97'

Comment: Also, what is try and except block?

Comment: That's alright! But, 'Jan-97' means it's probably a date type data (or, at the least a string)? So, likely shouldn't be used in correlation.

Comment: It's used for catching exceptions (i.e. where your code fails) - so, that you can use it to pivot to some other processing or debug, if needed.

Comment: Oh Ok ill have to look into that, I can probably handle dropping column with date from here... thanks for your help!